# Log in as System account on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, user-accounts

I am trying to configure a message queue on a windows server 2012 computer but I get 'access denied' errors, even if I log in as Administrator. Only the system account has the right permissions. How can I log in as system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

psexec -s cmd.exe

PsExec v2.11
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553

Comment: thanks. now when I type "whoami" on cmd it gives me "nt authority\system". However, I am still unable to change permissions of the message queue. I get the same access denied errors. Any ideas Greg?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing what the permission and ownership are.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/2uf7m10/8

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/155khua/8

Comment: are these any helpful?